# Passing Optional arguments to Grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bash-scripting

I am using `grep` to exclude lines containing certain strings.

The command I am using is

```
cat VlanConfig.txt | grep -vE $1\|$2\|$3
```

I want to keep the `$3` as optional argument.

It should accept two or more commands as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-e` parameter multiple times:

```
grep -v -e $1 -e $2 -e $3 -- VlanConfig.txt
```

Comment: grep: empty (sub)expression

Comment: I fixed my answer

Comment: cat VlanConfig.txt | grep -v -e $1 -e $2 -e $3

Comment: why above command gives error

Comment: Parameter `-e` must have argument. If `$3` is empty, You have `-e` without argument

Comment: Tomasz - unrelated to this question, but on several of your recent edits [1](http://superuser.com/questions/1133937/excel-2013-extract-different-texts-from-sentence), [2](http://superuser.com/questions/1133908/ms-excel-2013-autocomplete-cell-issue) you're using `code blocks` for elements that aren't code. In the future, would you please avoid using code for non-code unless formatting a specific table-type element? Otherwise, keep on editing!

Comment: @Raystafarian I think `code block` is the best solutions in these questions. But, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I'm not giving a suggestion, I'm letting you know the standard. You can ask on meta if you'd like, but `code` is for code. This isn't the place to discuss it but it was the best place I could find for the heads up.